# Wrong space in minted bash

Tags: minted

I have the following code:

```latex
\mint{bash}{printf "\xc3\xb1/"}
```

[image]

The syntax highlighting is nice, but it adds additional spaces in the wrong place. How can I avoid it?

I've compiled the document in my computer but it's the same as in Overleaf. My TeX version is:

> TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)

Pygments version:

> 2.2.0

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? I can't reproduce it with TeX Live 2019 (but neither with TL from 2014 onwards)..

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I'm using https://es.overleaf.com/project

Comment: That might depend on the version of Pygments available at Overleaf. Nothing that can be controlled on the LaTeX side, sorry. I can't access to your files.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to compile my document locally then. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg I compiled my document in my local environment with same results. My TeX version is TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)

Comment: I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJqdZ.png. There are no spaces at all.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I tested it with Pygments versions 2.1.3 and 2.2.0, and all TeX Live version from 2015 onwards and never got a space.